# Activities of all my friends on my wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get list of comments and likes on my wall made by all of my friends?
Answers using Facebook c#SDK will be great

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: @Will I think it's a question about the Facebook Graph API (seeing as it has the "facebook-graph" tag) - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Dude @will i have asked a very specific question related to coding.Please open it.

Comment: this is only on topic here if you're asking about the API.  I'm going to assume you are, but please edit your question with details on how you will be using the API.  Will also help get answers.

Comment: Thanks.  I know nothing of this thing you call Facebook.  But it is nice there is an API for c# applications so that they may interact with it.  I just hope that interaction is for good, and not evil.

Comment: Do you really want activities from your friends on *your wall* or on your *news feed*??

Answer (score 0):

you can call the Graph API (https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=YOURACCESSTOKEN) there you will see all posts on your wall...

Comment: i hope that's not a real access token. if it is yours, please remove it, since someone can take it and use it on your behalf

Comment: I want post of mine with facebook likes and comments so that i can get my friends details

Answer (score 0):

there are two phases in your problem.

first being able to get posts from a user's wall.

second part is what I will explain:

receive posts from the user wall. Each post has a 'from' field. from.id is the id of the poster. When the post is from a friend, that id in the post will not be equal to the id of the account owner.

I am doing this in PHP, but it is the same logic.

Comment: I want details of people who liked and commented on every post. PHP will be fine for me. I can convert it into c#